# post / upload image of movie to drupal 8 via vue js

Tags: post, vue.js, drupal-8

I'am trying to send files from `vuejs` to `drupal 8`. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Is there a question you have?  Are you having problems?  If you're getting an error, please let us know what the error says and what line it happens on.

Comment: yes the problem is how to send file with rest api drupal because the schema of file in drupal is like this 
field_image: [
{
target_id: "",
alt: "imag",
title: "",
width: "640",
height: "480",
url: ""
}
]
-The second problem is how to send both data and file with rest api

Comment: So are you getting an error that you need help with?

Answer (score -1):

my code doesnt work because the skeleton RestApi json is like this

[The skeleton json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtPRK.png)

but this code encode the file with encodebase64.